# How can I print the attribute of this class;; result is not returning as expected?

Tags: python, class

I'm currently writing a class Book and trying to print one of its attributes but keep getting the following returned instead :: `<__main__.Person object at 0x1055f5d68>`.

```
class Book:

     def __init__(self, title):

            self.title=title
            self.person=None
            self.waitlist=[]

     def __str__(self):

        if self.person!=None:
            result = str(self.person) 
        else:
           for person in self.waitlist:
               result += str(person)
        return result

     def borrow(self, person):

             if self.person==None:
                self.person=person
                return self.__str__()

                #This is where the message is coming. 
                #Rather than showing the person, it shows: 
                # <__main__.Person object at 0x1055f5d6>

             else:
                self.waitlist.append(person)
                return self.__str__()

                #I would also like to print the people in the waitlist here, but shows the same result.
```

I've tried printing the attribute person by using the methods `__repr__` and `__str__` as well, but it's not working in this case.
Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: In order for us to help you figure out why your `__str__` and/or `__repr__` methods are not working, you'll need to actually show those in your code. We can't debug what we can't see! (Though I guess it's `Person.__str__` you need to show.)

Comment: So I think your issue has to do with the thing I edited in to my last comment (so you might have missed it). You need to write a `__str__` method in the `Person` class, not (or maybe not only) in the `Book` class.